# Google Data Studio - How to get percentage of users who performed an event?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-data-studio

I have setup a dashboard where I could easily get the number of users who performed a certain event in a card. I have used the 'users' metric with a filter for the 'event category' and 'event action' and it gives me the number of users who performed this event.

What I really want to do is to display the percentage of the total users who performed the event. Instead of displaying 15 users performed the event I want to display 20% of users.

How can I achieve that? I cannot have a user metric filter and another without the filter to make the comparison. Am I missing something?

Comment: Since I'd never heard of Google Data Studio before, I'll share the link for it: https://www.google.com/analytics/data-studio/

Answer (score 1):

The answer, according to Google employee Rick E, is that there's not currently a way to do this:

https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/forums/v3_1/forumtopicpage/board-id/Data-Studio/thread-id/2055

The thread suggests the workaround of using the bar chart column style in a table or showing a pie chart. Neither of these are great solutions.

Other options are to do the calculations in GA (using calculated metrics) or using the [GA spreadsheet add-on](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/spreadsheet-add-on/) to pull data into Google Sheets, then manipulate this data and pull it into Data Studio.